# Mystified about the docker file system

Tags: docker, filesystems

Just getting started with docker. I've created an image, started a container  but when I write to a file in the container, it appears on my local disk. I'm mystified why this should be, and if it is like that how can I possibly run many instances of an image.

Here's what I do

```
docker container ls
 CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  
 CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
 5bf6d45b4f79        docker_1_web        "bundle exec rails s…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   docker_1_web_1
 d5d0991da014        postgres            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    5432/tcp                 docker_1_db_1
```

then

```
docker exec -it 5bf6d45b4f79 echo "hello" > temp.txt
```

and

```
docker exec -it 5bf6d45b4f79 cat temp.txt
hello
```

But on my local disk in my Mac command line

```
cat temp.txt
hello
```

Followed on my Mac command line by

```
echo "goodbye" >> temp.txt
cat temp.txt
hello
goodbye
```

And then in the container

```
docker exec -it 5bf6d45b4f79 cat temp.txt
hello
goodbye
```

Duh!!! How come? I thought docker containers wrote to their own filesystem. So I'm utterly mystified.

It also means that I can't run multiple instances of the image because they'd all be writing the the same files.

Answer (score 3):

Let's clarify this a little bit:

> When you do:
>
> ```
> docker exec -it 5bf6d45b4f79 echo "hello" > temp.txt
> docker exec -it 5bf6d45b4f79 cat temp.txt
> hello
> ```
>
> You're executing `echo "hello"` in your container but stdoutput is stored in your host. So, is normal that you see temp.txt in your host.

If you want to save temp.txt inside container, try:

```
docker exec -it 5bf6d45b4f79 bash -c "echo 'hello' > temp.txt"
```

And temp.txt will be generated on your container workdir.

> When you do:
>
> *But on my local disk in my Mac command line*
>
> ```
> cat temp.txt hello Followed on my Mac command line by
>
> echo "goodbye" >> temp.txt cat temp.txt hello goodbye
> ```
>
> *And then in the
>       container*
>
> ```
> docker exec -it 5bf6d45b4f79 cat temp.txt hello goodbye
> ```
>
> You're sharing temp.txt, maybe it's generated in a `docker volume` shared between host and docker

Comment: Ok, I see I just followed the instructions on the Docker web site and it didn't explain the significance of this line in docker-compose.yml `volumes:
      - .:/myapp` (darn my replies can't include newlines). Which creates a volume shared with the local drive. Somehow I have to put stuff into a volume that isn't shared with the local drive. I've given up and I'm creating a VM using docker-engine.

Comment: Ok, but consider that didn't engine doesn't crease VM exactly. It's a little bit different VM than a container.

Answer (score 1):

```
docker exec -it 5bf6d45b4f79 echo "hello" > temp.txt
```

makes your container print `hello` and then `> temp.txt` takes this output and  generates a file on your **host**.

To make your container print `hello` and then create a `temp.txt` inside **itself**, you will have to use:

```
docker container exec -it <your_container_name> sh -c 'echo "hello" > temp.txt'
```

---

## Explained:

`sh -c` creates a new shell inside the container and runs `echo "hello" > temp.txt'`. This means that the `> temp.txt` part will be handled by this shell and as a result the file is created inside the container.

The way you were trying to do it, it is the shell of your **host** which handles the `> temp.txt` part of your command and as a result the file is created on your host.

Comment: Please, if my answer helped you, mark it as solved, not only invite, please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get a terminal of the docker container & open a separate window for the Host. But that's just how I do it.
`docker exec -it 5bf6d45b4f79 /bin/bash`